# Voltar no menu Android

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, android-layout, android-xml

Tem um menu dentro de um menu, como voltar no menu anterior?

```
<menu xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item
    android:id="@+id/opcMenu"
    android:title="Menu"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />


<item
    android:id="@+id/opcPerfil"
    android:title="Perfil"/>
<item
    android:id="@+id/mTarefas"
    android:title="Tarefas">
    <menu>
        <item android:id="@+id/opcAddTarefa"
            android:title="Adicionar Tarefas" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/opcNotas"
            android:title="Notas" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/opcTarefas"
            android:title="Ver Tarefas" />
        <item
            android:id="@+id/opcVoltar"
            android:title="←"/>
    </menu>
</item>


<item
    android:id="@+id/opcAjuda"
    android:title="Ajuda" />
<item
    android:id="@+id/opcSair"
    android:title="Sair" />
```